# Derivative of Binary Cross Entropy is always negative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, neural-networks

I'm trying to find derivatives of a back propogation algorithm.

Given a loss function $$L(\hat y_i, y_i) = \sum - y_i log (\hat y_i)$$ where $\hat y_i = \sigma(z)$ and $z = Wx + b$. Find the update of weight $\frac{dL}{dw}$.

$$\frac{dL}{dw} = \frac{dL}{d\hat y_i}\frac{d\hat y_i}{dz}\frac{dz}{dw}$$

Now, the last 2 terms are always positive (given $x>0$), since the derivative of the sigmoid is bounded by $0$ and $1$.

Now for the $\frac{dL}{d\hat y_i}$ part, it seems that it's always negative, and equal to:
$$\frac{dL}{d\hat y_i} = -\sum \frac{y_i}{\hat y_i}$$

Now this doesn't make intuitive sense, because what is the point of having a learning rate $\lambda$, if the weight update is always in the same direction?

Given random weight initialisations, $w$ can only get bigger.

$$w_i = w_i - \lambda \frac{dL}{dw}$$

Comment: Is it obvious that $y_i$ and $\hat{y}_i$ have the same sign?

Comment: @user113102 Both of them are simply probabilities, so yes, they should be bounded by $[0,1]$

Comment: Ok then. I guess the question is why does your loss function make sense as a loss function? Don't I always want to push the $\hat{y}_i$'s in one direction independent of what $y_i$ is?

Comment: Like you’re missing a $-(1-y_i)\log(1-\hat{y}_i)$ term, no?

Comment: @user113102 Yes, that's the question. I just rewrote $y_0 = p(y=0)$ and $y_1= p(y=1)$, and hence $\hat y_1 = 1 - \hat y_0$. This means I can technically rewrite it as: $\frac{dL}{d\hat y} = - \sum (\frac{y_0}{\hat y_0} + \frac{y_1}{\hat y_1})$. I think the problem is I'm mixing up the indexes, and what they mean.

Comment: Ah yeah usually for loss functions, you're summing over (and the indices indicate) examples. Like the left hand side of your first equation is "the loss of prediction $i$", whereas on the right hand side you're using $i$ for something different.

So if we keep it expanded out, $$\frac{dL}{d\hat{y}_i} = -\frac{y_i}{\hat{y}_i} + \frac{1-y_i}{1-\hat{y}_i},$$ which can be positive or negative.